# xcode screenshot with advertisement

Tags: ios, screenshot, admob

I use this to save a screenshot of the app when pushing a button:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_containerView.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

It used to take things correctly (i.e. everything on the screen) but now puts a white bar where the advertisement is (iAd/AdMob) and it just looks ugly.  It looks much better with the ad in the screenshot.  Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Hi David... this question doesn't have anything to do with Xcode but instead it's with iOS.  Do you want the ad to be in the screenshot or could the ad view be completely removed from the image written to the photo album?

Comment: Either way is ok,... I just don't like the white bar that results from the ad sun view I guess.

Comment: You can take screenshots with xcode and organizer while running the app.  Or on your running device by pressing the home and power button at the same time.  Do you  really need to take the screenshot programmatically?

Comment: Yes as the screenshot ends getting uploaded. If you take a screenshot with the phone for example IRS fine.

Comment: Ok, is the admob view inside of _containerView?  Try using the ViewController's view property in the code snippet above.

Comment: Ok I'll try that... I'm away from the computer for a little. I'll post the result.

Comment: I guess I’m not really sure where/how to do that?